# Cannot find method setHandleFault(java.lang.Boolean) in CamelContext in camel 3.x

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to upgrade **camel** from version 2.22.2 to 3.14.10 and getting below error:

```
Code: getContext().setHandleFault(Boolean.TRUE);
 
Error:
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setHandleFault(java.lang.Boolean)
[ERROR]   location: interface org.apache.camel.CamelContext
```

Note: Here getContext() is method of RouteBuilder.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is removed, see the camel 2 -> 3.x upgrade docs
https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html